# Issue about casting object brackets

Tags: java, object, casting

I have noticed that there are two ways to cast objects (the difference is the placement of the outer parenthesis):

```
 1. SimpleType simpleType = ((SimpleType) (property.getType()));
 2. SimpleType simpleType = ((SimpleType) property).getType();
```

Are they doing the same thing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are they doing the same thing ?

**No** they are not.

- The first one is casting your value returned from
  `property.getType()` to `SimpleType`. (*Invocation* is done before *Casting*)
- The second one is first casting your `property` to `SimpleType` and
  then invoking the `getType()` method on it. (*Casting* is done before *Invocation*).

---

You can also understand it from the precedence of *parenthesis*. Since it has the highest precedence, it will be evaluated first.

**First Case: -**

So, in `((SimpleType) (property.getType()));`: -

```
(property.getType())
```

is evaluated first, then the casting is performed. In fact you don't really need a parenthesis around that. (`property` binds tighter to the `dot (.)` operator than the `cast` operator). So, invocation will always be done before casting. Unless you force it to reverse as in the below case: -

**Second Case : -**

In `((SimpleType) property).getType()`: -

```
((SimpleType) property)
```

is evaluated first, then the invocation is done. As, now you have enclosed `property` inside the brackets, due to which it *binds* tighter to the `cast` operator, due to higher precedence enforced by *parenthesis*.

Answer (score 5):

They are doing two totally unrelated things: first is dowcasting the result of `getType()` and the second is downcasting the `property` variable. The first one looks like the one you need, given the type of the left-hand side. Note that in the first example you have extra parentheses, this would be enough, and is how this is idiomatically written:

```
SimpleType simpleType = (SimpleType) property.getType();
```

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same.

- The first casts the result of `getType` to `SimpleType`.
- The second casts `property` to `SimpleType` and calls `getType` on it, yet the result of `getType` is not casted to `SimpleType`.

Answer (score 1):

They are entirely doing diffrent things. they are not same at all.

```
 1. SimpleType simpleTypee = ((SimpleType) (property.getType()));
```

This first invokes getType of property and then casts the returned Object to SimpleType

```
 2. SimpleType simpletype = ((SimpleType) property).getType();
```

This first casts the property to SimpleType and then invokes getType on the SimpleType

Answer (score 1):

No they are not doing the same thing.

```
SimpleType simpleTypee = ((SimpleType) (property.getType()));
```

First the `property.getType()` will be called and the object returned by `property.getType()` will be casted to `SimpleType`

and in the second case

```
SimpleType simpletype = ((SimpleType) property).getType();
```

first the object `property` will be casted to `SimpleType` and then `getType()` will be invoked on that newly casted object

Answer (score 1):

They are doing different things as detailed in the other answers. You can also cast by doing this

```
SimpleType.class.cast(property.getType());
SimpleType.class.cast(property).getType();
```

Depending on what you actaully want to cast. Either property or the result of getType(). I prefer this syntax as it is more explicit and easier on the eye...